# HttpHostConnectException when initializing WireMock HTTP server

Tags: wiremock, httphostconnectexception

I'm trying to test my code that has an underlying GET call to an HTTP server.

I am trying to use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org), and base on the "Getting Started" I have the following code:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = 
    new WireMockRule(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().port(8888)); // No-args constructor defaults to port 8080

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass(){
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/Path/Get"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody("[1]")));
}

@Test
public void testGetRanking() throws Exception {
    Fetcher fetcher = new Fetcher("http://localhost:8888",null);
    int rankinganking = fetcher.getRanking("Max");
    Assert.assertEquals(1, ranking);
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following stack-trace:

```
wiremock.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
at wiremock.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
at wiremock.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at wiremock.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at wiremock.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
...
```

The error talks about port 8080, but I configured the port to be 8888. I know that by default WireMock starts with port 8080, so this might be an issue with its internal configuration.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `@BeforeClass` executes before `@rule`.
Moving the stubbing into a `@Before` method or straight into the test solves the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as described above. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34379236/7435524) didn't resolve my problem. It's still trying to spin the server on the same port 8080. Although, the one specified is 8888. Anyone has an idea. My code is literally the same as in the [Getting Started](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) guide.

Comment: Like @KareemJeiroudi I have the same problem and it doesn't resolve this error.